# How to sort and copy numbered files into incremented folders

Tags: bash, directory-structure

So I have gene files named 1, 2, ... 19500.fa and want to sort them into folders 200, 400, 600... 19600 for a downstream pipeline. I have an idea of how to do this but it's pretty gruesome:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do

    base_name=$(basename "$file")
    gene_number=$(echo "$base_name" | cut -d'_' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1)
    to_path= (path to folder containing 200, 400, ... 19600 folders)
    
    #if it's gene_200.fa, 400.fa etc. copy into that dir
    if (( $gene_number%200 == 0)); then 
        cp file $to_path/$gene_number/$file
    elif (( $gene_number < 200 )); then 
        cp file $to_path/200/$file
    elif (( $gene_number > 19400)); then 
        cp file $to_path/19600/$file
    # the endless pain of 200-400, 400-600, 600-800 ... 19200-19400
    elif (( $gene_number > 200 && $gene_number < 400)); then 
        cp file $to_path/19600/$file
    elif ....
```

My question is then: is there a less tedious way to do this without copying any one file into multiple folders? (e.g. if i only sorted by gene number < file name a file named gene_3.fa would be copied into all folders)

Comment: You "want to sort them into folders", but at the same time, you want to do this "without copying files into multiple folders". Is not that contradictory? Are you looking into creating soft links? I'm not sure I'm getting your issue, it does not make sense to me.

Comment: these 19k + files are all in one folder. I want each gene file to only be in one of the smaller folders named 200, 400, 600. I am trying to avoid the issue where a file named gene_3.fa is copied into every folder for example if i sorted only by the condition gene number is less than file name.

Comment: What exactly does it mean to "sort files into folder"? You want to _move_ files into folders? __or__ do you want to create symlinks in folder? __or__ do you want to _print_ a list of files? The code you are showing _copies_ the files. I do not understand how to answer "is there a less tedious way to do this without copying files" without a clear definition what does "sort and copy" files mean.

Comment: Yes I agree, I want to copy them into these folders. By sort I mean that I am organizing them by number, not just any 200 files in any folder.

Comment: So you want `cp $file $to_path/$((gene_number / 200 * 200))/$file`? To _floor_ a number, just divide it, because it's integers, the numbers after comma will be cut.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the line but won't this just send a file like gene_3.fa to a folder named 3? I am trying to copy gene_1.fa - gene_200.fa into folder 200, gene_201.fa - gene_400.fa into folder 400, and so on.

Comment: Isn't this simply a mathematical problem? If you have a gene number x, then it should be copied into folder with number `200*((x div 200) + 1)`, where _div_ is the integer division; isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, just change the `for` to loop over the files, change the `delta` value to `200` and add the `cp` or `mv` as you like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

delta=5
for file in gene_{1..20}.fa; do
    if [[ "$file" =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
        gene_number="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
        bucket=$(( ((gene_number / delta) * delta) + delta ))
        echo "$file -> $bucket"
    fi
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
gene_1.fa -> 5
gene_2.fa -> 5
gene_3.fa -> 5
gene_4.fa -> 5
gene_5.fa -> 10
gene_6.fa -> 10
gene_7.fa -> 10
gene_8.fa -> 10
gene_9.fa -> 10
gene_10.fa -> 15
gene_11.fa -> 15
gene_12.fa -> 15
gene_13.fa -> 15
gene_14.fa -> 15
gene_15.fa -> 20
gene_16.fa -> 20
gene_17.fa -> 20
gene_18.fa -> 20
gene_19.fa -> 20
gene_20.fa -> 25
```

The math works because bash does integer arithmetic, not floating point, and so the part after the decimal point after the division will be truncated.